# Using SQLite connection in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite in a C# app but I have a problem:

I followed this guide:
http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

And my code is:

```
namespace MyDB
{
    internal class SQLiteConnector_Local
    {
        private SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

        public SQLiteConnector_Local() {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");

            m_dbConnection.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS singleOptions (key_column VARCHAR(50), value_column VARCHAR(80))", m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            m_dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have an Exception on the line:

```
m_dbConnection.Open();
```

The exception is:

```
An exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code.
```

Yes, the exception must be handled, but my main problem is why I have this exception?

I searched the solution in others questions but I have not found it.

Comment: Edited. Check the path or try to specify absolute paths

Comment: is the path to the db correct? e.g. Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite- where is MyDatabase.sqlite created?

Comment: Yes. With the CreateFile command, the file is created in the executable directory, and  the connection I think that try to open the file in the same directory too. I tried with absolute paths but I have the same problem.

Comment: It's not a solution, but you could use `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` to create your connection string. In my opinion, building the connection string himself is source of error.

Comment: I test with the connection string builder but as you say this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my previous Windows installation, SQLite worked fine in a previous similar project. All the time I have been thinking that there is something wrong with my new code.

I still have the executables used in my previous Windows installation and I have checked that the versions are not the same (previous executables was a bundle version).

I have uninstalled SQLite libraries and reinstalled the bundle version, and now it works fine!